# How can I create a client side rendering react app with NX?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to create a micro frontend project using react and module federation should I use NX ? if yes how can I create a client side rendering application with NX

I tried SSR with NX and it worked but I need to do client side rendering too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.